# Not sure what this line of code does in c

Tags: c, syntax, msp430

```
tempValue = input2[0] << 8;
```

I can't figure out what the `<<` does in this line of code.  What is this used for?

Comment: If you have no book or tutorial available where you can look up fundamental language syntax, I'd say you are in quite a bit of trouble.

Comment: If you don't know operators, you cannot know the precedence, thus you cannot undestatn anything. You must start from the beginning, not by looking at some "complicated" code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It assigns `tempValue` the value in `input2[0]` shifted to the left by 8 bits.

Here is a link about bit shifting in C: http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/bitshift.html

Comment: Alright!! That was exactly my answer. For future reference do you have any idea how I could search for something like that on google?

Comment: @KevinMcAtee I knew what it was called from experience.  I suggest looking at a C reference book for operators and their names.  I suppose Google doesn't know what `<<` means.  In a nutshell, try a book first :).

Comment: @KevinMcAtee: Search for “C operators”.

Answer (score 0):

You can google **Bitwise Operation** for many information.

In your case, input2[0] being **Left shift(<<)** for 8 bits, which is * (2^8).

So, equivalent `tempValue = input2[0] * (2^8) ;`